# Can Elixir script or iex use external modules without creating a new project?

Tags: elixir

I often write HTTP program with using [HTTPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) in Elixir.
Of course if I use **mix** for creating new project and modify mix.exs for dependency for HTTPoison, `mix deps.get` can resolve dependencies.

However, sometimes I want to try short scripts (.exs) or iex for simple experiment which require external modules without creating a new project.

Are there any methods to solve this requirement like 'libraries search path' in Elixir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Code` module has functions to implement all the things you need. However, it only works with existing files on the machine and you'll need to do pretty much everything "manually".

```
Code.append_path

Code.ensure_loaded
```

should accomplish most of what you want.

Another approach is to use `iex -S mix` in an existing project with
the dependencies and then load the .exs file.

Comment: Thaks. However using mix.exs with a new project seems to be right and convenient way in the end.

Answer (score 0):

`erun` might be helpful.
It wraps Mix dependencies in escript, and you can run your scripts as

```
$ erun foo.exs
```

https://github.com/s417-lama/erun